# How does a dictionary whose key is a List behave?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with legacy code and I see a dictionary whose key is a list of objects...

```
var myCrazyDictionary = new Dictionary<List<MyKeyObject>, List<MyValueObject>>();
```

How does such a dictionary behave? You know, because of reference types...

Is it working magically like so?

```
// ????
myCrazyDictionary.Add(new List<MyKeyObject> { new MyKeyObject { Key1 = "1", Key2 = 2 } }, new List<MyValueObject> { new MyValueObject { Value = "!" } });

// ???????????
var result = myCrazyDictionary[new List<MyKeyObject> { new MyKeyObject { Key1 = "1", Key2 = 2 } }];
// Will this hold the value: "!" or crash or something else?
var byWhatBlackMagic = result[0].Value;
```

Comment: Download the [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net), put your code there and test it yourself. Or Visual Studio 2015 has an integrated REPL.

Comment: You probably should write your own class to hold the key values. Make sure that the key doesn't change (ideally by making it an immutable type).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be have the same as if you did a dictionary `Dictionary<Object, List<MyValueObject>>` and just did a `new Object()` for both the add and retrieval. `List<T>` does not override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` so it just uses the default behavior which only compares object references. It will not look inside of the list to compare. So your example will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` when you try to do `myCrazyDictionary[new List<MyKeyObject> { ... }]` because you are creating a "new object" and that new object is not in the dictionary (because you just created it).

You can get the functionality you want, you just need to make a custom `IEqualityComparer<List<MyKeyObject>>` and pass it in to the constructor of your dictionary.

**Be aware!** If you do make a custom comparer nothing in your `List<MyKeyObject>` that is associated with your custom `Equals(List<MyKeyObject>, List<MyKeyObject>)` nor your custom `.GetHashCode(List<MyKeyObject>)` can be changed while it is acting as the roll of a key or you will break the internal logic of `Dictionary`.

Comment: Yep, looking at the [source code for List](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs/), I verified that `List<T>` does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @minghan You can also check by [looking at the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), if a method is overridden it will say "*(Overrides Object.Equals(Object).)*" and if it is not overriden it will say "*(Inherited from Object.)*" (see the [MSDN for `Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) for a example of it overridden). Checking the source is a "implementation detail" and may be subject to change, anything on the MSDN is a "contract" and behavior is guaranteed not to change between .NET versions unless noted in remarks